# Does booting in UEFI mode require the "bootmgr" file?

Tags: boot, partitioning

A few days ago I observed the files "bootmgr" and "BOOTNXT" at the root of the C: drive. They haven't been there before. When I searched "bootmgr" up, I found out that it manages the booting process in Windows and that it's located at the root of the partition that is marked as 'active'. But it's still not clear to me if this file is needed if you always boot in UEFI mode and the disk is partitioned using the GPT. I also found out that there is no need for an active partition if the boot mode is set to UEFI, that's why I don't understand why it's present on C:. So here are my questions: Do I need to keep "bootmgr" and "BOOTNXT" if I'm sure that I'll always boot in UEFI mode? And do I need them if I want to dual boot Windows with Ubuntu or Linux Mint? Can I delete them, should I leave them where they are or should I move them to the EFI partition? NOTE: I also noticed that there exists a file called "bootmgr.efi" on the EFI partition, but that's not the one I'm meaning.

Comment: Yes; It’s required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The EFI version of the Windows Boot Manager is named `Bootmgfw.efi` in and is usually stored in your EFI System Partition at `\EFI\Microsoft`.